# Discord bot js - Cant get channel by id

Tags: discord.js

This is my code. The output of 'channel' is always undefined. Does someone know the problem?

```js
var channelId = "myId";

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(token);

var channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
console.log(channel);
```

Comment: Since the bot is not ready. If you run your last 2 rows inside the ready function, you will get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.login(token)` returns a `promise` so it's highly unlikely that you're authenticated when `client.channels.cache.get(channelId)` runs.

You should try changing your code to the below, so that you get your channel after you've authenticated.

```
client.login(token).then(x => { 
    var channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
    console.log(channel);
});
```